# Save stream as parquet given by-element path

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet

I would like to save (`parquet`) each value of a stream to a specific directory which path is given by the key. There should be less than five different keys, as many different directories.

As I did not find any example of what I want to do, I tried the following approach: `filter()` the stream by each key found inside; with the following code:

```scala
stream
      .foreachRDD{ (rdd, time) =>
        import spark.implicits._

        if (rdd.take(1).length != 0) {
          val directories= rdd.map(_._1).distinct().collect()
          lDates.foreach { directory =>
            rdd
              .filter(_._1==directory).map(_._2)
              .toDF()
              .write.format("parquet").mode("append").save(directory)
          }
        }
      }
```

But the barbaric `collect()` takes a heavy toll on the computation and leads to some `scheduling delay`...

Would anyone have a better way to implement this or improve performance?

EDIT: I do not have access to Structured streaming.

Comment: Collect will try to bring all your data to driver. That is costly operation. Avoid "collect"  & let spark executors write to desired directory

Comment: This I wrote. The problem stems from "the desired directory" hold by the keys, the `save()` operation can not access to from within the stream..

Comment: look at Structured Streaming

Comment: Yes, you are right it would answer my problem. But, I forgot to precise I do not have access to it.